# Accessing Youtube's GET Parameters from Youtube Masthead

Tags: youtube, banner, query-string, banner-ads

Can a custom GET Parameter (e.g. customParam) in Youtube's URL _e.g. [Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/?customParam=123) be accessible from Youtube Masthead?

Answer (score 1):

it will not work... if you really want to build custom Youtube Masthead go through this documenation `https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/6098114?hl=en&ref_topic=6098218`